# Android Studio: Where do I have to put assets and res?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Where do I have to put the folders assets and res to? In assets/gfx, there are some .png images, and in res/layout and /values, there are some .xml files.

Comment: What do you mean by `assets` and `res`? Image files, Fonts?

Comment: Yes. These are folders.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. :<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assets and res folders should be in the same level as your java folder:

[image]